# Is there an Azure Websites functionality equivalent to Azure Web Roles RoleEntryPoint

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-roles

I want to run some code from a library before Application_Start and i was wondering if that is possible using just Azure websites or if I have to purchase an Azure Web Role instance and use RoleEntryPoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the [WebActivator](http://nuget.org/packages/WebActivator) NuGet package? Have a look on [GitHub](https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator) for further details but the basics of it are simply adding an attribute and an initialisation method to your application. For example:

```
using System;

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyApp.Bootstrapper), "PreStart")]

namespace MyApp {
    public static class Bootstrapper {
        public static void PreStart() {
            // Add your start logic here
        }
    }
}
```

The code in `PreStart` will run before Application_Start.

There are other attributes you can use for doing things on shutdown (`ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute`) and for post startup (`PostApplicationStartMethodAttribute`).

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm looking for.  Do you know if this requires the web app to be accessed by a client browser like Application_Start does or will this code execute without any client interaction?

Comment: It requires the application pool to spin up first. The only way you could mitigate that would be to configure the application pool to always run but I'd suspect that isn't doable in Azure Websites...